# Python String - need to print an string with double quote at end

Tags: python-3.x

I need to print the statement - He said - "I'am not coming today" but when it is enclosed in three double quotes as below -

```
print("""He said - "I'am not coming today"""")
```

error is thrown - SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

While if use

```
print("""He said - "I'am not coming today\"""")
```

it is printed.

Please help me to understand what is wrong in first print.

Comment: Simple but good question. Can you check answers please. It's because, using extra `"` at the end is breaking the syntax to create multiline string. So that is why, we need to use escape sequence as `\"` to escape it. In middle, it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `"""` for this.

```
print("He said - \"I\'am not coming today\"")
```

You need to `escape (\)` the quotes so python knows you want the literal quote marks.

Note, since you use `"` you do not need to escape the `'` but it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `"""` pair is basically used to create multi-line string. So, adding 1 more `"` and use `""""` goes beyond the syntax and that is why we need to escape it using `\"` to make `"` as part of the string at end. While placing it in middle is okay.

> Wrong

```
>>> print("""He said - "I'am not coming today"""")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("""He said - "I'am not coming today"""")
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>>
```

> Correct (using `\"` is correct choice to make `"` as part of string at end)

```
>>> print("""He said - "I'am not coming today\"""")
He said - "I'am not coming today"
>>>
```

**Note 1:** In case of using `"` to surround string, `\"` is mandatory to make `"` as part of the string wherever it may be.

```
>>> print("He said - \"I'am not coming today\"")
He said - "I'am not coming today"
>>>
```

**Note 2:** But in case of using `'` it is not required (Here you will need to use `\'` to make `'` as part of string).

```
>>> print('He said - "I\'am not coming today"')
He said - "I'am not coming today"
>>>
```

Comment: @hygull You copy-pasted the wrong text, it's `print("""He said - "I'am not coming today\"""")` with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you very much you both @Guimoute. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, I've updated my answer.